# How to solve an equation with vectors

Tags: vectors

I have the equation $s = |v + at|$ where $v$ and $a$ are 2 dimensional vectors, $s$ and $t$ are scalars.

I am trying to rearrange this equation to solve for t, this should have two (or zero) solutions.

I can break out the vector components ($a$ = ($a$, $b$), $v$ = ($v$, $u$)) to get the equation $s = (v + at)^2 + (u + bt)^2$. However, when I solve this on wolfram-alpha I get two very large equations for the solution. I wonder if the solutions will be simpler when represented with vector operations?

If this is possible to solve, please provide the steps.

Comment: The vector operation most helpful in this situation is: $x\cdot x=|x|^2$.

Comment: $s^2=|v+at|^2=|v|^2+2t(v,a)+t^2|a|^2$. Or wait, from what you are saying it looks like $|\cdot|$ might not be the norm of the vector. Two equations? What is $|\cdot|$? The norm, or maybe componentwise absolute value?

Comment: @SphericalTriangle the magnitude, but even a solution for magnitude squared is fine

Comment: Then you get only one equation $s^2=|v|^2+2t(v,a)+t^2|a|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that

$$s^2=|v+at|^2=(v+at)\cdot(v+at)=|v|^2+2(v\cdot a)t+t^2|a|^2.$$

Given that $|a|\not=0$, we can rearrange to

$$0=t^2+\underbrace{\frac{2(v\cdot a)}{|a|^2}}_{=:\,p}t+\underbrace{\frac{|v|^2-s^2}{|a|^2}}_{=:\,q}=t^2+pt+q.$$

You should be able to solve a quadratic equation for its two solutions $t_{1/2}$.